# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkcalendar'

Tags: python, tkinter, pip, python-3.7, tkcalendar

I have installed tkcalendar using `pip3 install tkcalendar` and it says that it has installed successfully. However, when i run the line `from tkcalendar import *` in my program, it gives me  `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkcalendar'`. Can anybody help?

Comment: Your `pip3` installed the package for a different Python, not that one you use to run the script. `python --version`, `pip --version`, `which python`, `which pip`, etc.

Comment: how do i move the package to my actual version of python

Comment: You shouldn't because packages, especially written in C, are fragile and cannot be moved. Install with a proper version of `pip` or `python -m pip`.

Comment: Install it from the  `IDE` you are using

Comment: (1) Find the directory where `tkcalendar` was installed in. (2) Make sure that that directory is in your PATH environment variable. if it isn't there, you need to update your PATH. Issue the command `echo $PATH` in your terminal to see your PATH value.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that when you're running your file you use python3. I was having the same issue because I just used python and it reverted to python2

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and since I was new to this I searched everywhere and couldn't find a solution that worked. Finally I moved the cursor to line 'from tkcalendar import *' (right over tkcalendar)  and a pop-up gave me a link to install tkcalendar. That seemed to be all there was to it. I tried pip install tkcalendar several times and even pip3 to see what it would do. Nothing worked except for what I just mentioned above.